# Problem with MissingDataMethod

Tags: list-manipulation, interpolation

Given

```
v = {2, 1, Missing[], 5, 7, 4};
```

I use `EventSeries` to replace the missing value with its predecessor

```
EventSeries[v, MissingDataMethod -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 0}]["Values"]
```

> {2, 1, 1, 5, 7, 4}

If the last value is missing

```
v = {2, 1, 1, 5, 7, Missing[]};
```

I get again the expected result

> {2, 1, 1, 5, 7, 7}

but also the error message

> InterpolatingFunction::dmval:Input value {-5} lies outside the range
>   of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.

Why is that so?

Comment: It seems reasonable to me that extrapolation must be used in the second case, since your data series proper ends before the missing point. You would only be able to use interpolation for missing values that occur within your data series. However, if your question is about why the input value passed to `Interpolation` is $-5$, then that is confusing to me as well.

Comment: Note, that in the case of `InterpolationOrder -> 1` the warning will be issued with the "correct" value of `{5}`.

Comment: The comment by @MarcoB is correct. I'll add that the cryptic error message with a `-5` is a known issue, but is harmless.

Comment: Thanks, Marco and Stefan - so I'll just use `Quiet`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  the issued raised is not really a problem, but a misunderstanding of a warning message by the OP.